# KKT maximization problem

Tags: optimization, nonlinear-optimization, karush-kuhn-tucker

> $x^2y \rightarrow$ max,
>
> such that $x^2 + 4xy \leq 1, x \geq 0$ and $y \geq 0$.

I think I need to use the KKT conditions here. I did however not yet succeed in solving it, so could someone please give me an example of how this should be done? And should I include the constraints $x \geq 0$ and $y \geq 0$ into the Lagrangian function?

Comment: Since $x^2+4xy\le1$ and $x,y\ge0$, we have $y\le\frac{1-x^2}{4x}$, so $x^2 y\le x^2\times\frac{1-x^2}{4x}=\frac{x(1-x^2)}{4}\le\frac{\sqrt{3}}{18}.$

Comment: @asatzhh Thanks! Nice find! But could you maybe also explain me how this problem would be solved using the KKT conditions? And how does your last inequality follow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The KKT conditions in this case for $x,y$ that are feasible ($x\geq0,y\geq0,x^2+4xy\leq1$) is that $\exists \alpha,\beta,\gamma\geq0$ (feasible dual variables for the constraints in the last parens in respective order) such that

1. Stationary: $2xy=-\alpha+\gamma(2x+4y)$, $x^2=-\beta+\gamma x^2$, and
2. Complementary slackness: $\alpha x=\beta y=\gamma(x^2+4xy-1)=0$

However, the problem is not convex therefore KKT conditions are not sufficient. In particular, the eigenvalues of the hessian of your objective are $y\pm\sqrt{4x^2+y^2}$ so that one of them is always positive (so not concave for a maximization problem) and also one is negative whenever $x>0$ which is certainly feasible (so it's not even definite in either direction).

But they are necessary. So you can guess which constraints are active or not and go through all permutations of this to find all KKT-satisfying points. For example, guess that the nonnegativity constraints are slack ($\alpha=\beta=0$) and that the other constraint is tight ($x^2+4xy=1$). Then plugging this into the KKT conditions we get three equations:
$$2xy=\gamma(2x+4y)$$
$$(1-\gamma)x^2=0$$
$$x^2+4xy=1$$
Which solve for $x=1/\sqrt{3}$ and $y=1/\sqrt{12}$ and give objective value $1/\sqrt{108}$. (Hint: this is optimal.)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your explanation! Very helpful. Could you explain to me what the difference is between sufficient and necessary?

Comment: Necessary conditions for optimality must hold for an optimal solution. Sufficient conditions hold only for optimal solutions. For convex optimization problems, KKT conditions are both necessary and sufficient so they are an exact characterization of optimality. Convexity of a problem means that the feasible space is a convex set and that over the feasible space the objective is convex if minimizing or concave if maximizing.

Comment: Sorry for asking only now, but I tried following the same procedure as you did, and I arrive at slightly different conditions for stationary points. Could you please specify the Lagrange function that you used (and/or how exactly you got these?). Did you use $\mathcal{L}=x^2y-\alpha x - \beta y + \gamma (x^2+4xy-1)$?

Comment: Somehow, I get the exact same end-result as you do, however, some of my Lagrange-multipliers are negative, which should not be the case. So I'm extremely curious what you did differently.